# Infer.NET vs ML.NET (Microsoft Machine Learning Frameworks)

Tags: machine-learning, frameworks, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

After Microsoft becoming more open source friendly, I started to see more and more emphasis on Machine Learning such as ML.NET and Infer.NET.
I want to know, what is the difference between two, since both are coming from Microsoft. What will be pros and cons of both frameworks?

Comment: According to this source infer .net is more advanced because it constructs algorithm (sim) using Bayesian analysis instead of reusing  a generic one..  https://www.google.com/amp/s/mspoweruser.com/microsofts-popular-machine-learning-framework-infer-net-goes-open-source/amp/

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/10/08/announcing-ml-net-0-6-machine-learning-net/

> **Infer.NET is now open-source and becoming part of the ML.NET family**
>
> On October 5th 2018, Microsoft Research announced the open-sourcing of
>   Infer.NET – a cross-platform framework for model-based machine
>   learning.
>
> Infer.NET differs from traditional machine learning frameworks in that
>   it requires users to specify a statistical model of their problem.
>   This allows for high interpretability, incorporating domain knowledge,
>   doing unsupervised/semi-supervised learning, as well as online
>   inference – the ability to learn as new data arrives. The approach and
>   many of its applications are described in our free online book for
>   beginners.
>
> Places where Infer.NET is used at Microsoft include TrueSkill – a
>   skill rating system for matchmaking in Halo and Gears of War, Matchbox
>   – a recommender system in Azure Machine Learning, and Alexandria –
>   automatic knowledge base construction for Satori, to name a few.
>
> We’re working with the Infer.NET team to make it part of the ML.NET
>   family. Steps already taken in this direction include releasing under
>   the .NET Foundation and changing the package name and namespaces to
>   Microsoft.ML.Probabilistic.

Answer (score -4):

ML.Net is for .Net Developers and Infer.Net is for open source Developer but both of them for machine learning concepts and algorithms.

Comment: I think you have a misconception on what open source means... both are open sourced and both are for .Net developers.

Comment: @c-chavez ya I got little confusion on those both, ML.Net and Infer.Net both are open source you were right.